# Checking if an audio file is playing

Tags: osx, python, audio

I need to know if an audio file is currently playing so that a python script can wait before playing a new audio file. I am using OSX. The python script is using the 'os' module to spawn a subshell and play an mp3 file using 'afplay'. This script may be called twice in rapid succession. I am trying to avoid playing multiple files at once. Ideally I'd like to have the script wait for the end of the audio file that is currently playing before playing the next. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you forking out to `afplay(1)` or how are the files being played? Or does the code need to be aware if `iTunes` or the like is active?

Comment: I imported os into my python script and am currently playing audio files through a subshell with afplay

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more detail. We need to know exactly how the files are being played.

Comment: @terdon edits have been made

Comment: A lockfile would be one solution, so that subsequent instances will fail if some other instance has a lock on a file. Python probably has modules for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution to making sure only one (of a cooperating set of programs) is doing something at once is a mutex of some sort. In this case, you'd obtain the mutex before the `afplay` call, and release it right after `afplay` finishes. This will guarantee that you're only running one `afplay` at a time.

You have several choices for inter-process mutexes, but the easiest is probably the lock file. I don't personally know Python, but Stack Overflow has “[Locking a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python)” which appears to give plenty of options.